# How to structure data that can be both indexed and sorted on different keys?

Tags: java, collections

I'd like to maintain a set of data that has two main attributes: 1. I can quickly look up the existence of an object by a numerical ID, and 2. I want to sort the data, but avoid needlessly sorting it since it can be slow.  For a more concrete example, I have a set of user data, where each user has a unique ID (an int) and a unique username (a String).  I'll be adding and removing users, and occasionally I want to generate a human-readable, alphabetically-sorted list to the user, but as my number of users increases, so does the time needed to sort the data.

How would you structure this?  The only reasonable approach I can think of involves creating two separate data structures, and redundantly add/remove items to BOTH structures at the same time.  As my data grows, it will be using more data than a single structure would.  I might also introduce more bugs this way, as I have to remind myself to duplicate the operations to both structures when I come back to add to the code later.  In other words, I could have:

```
TreeMap<String,Integer> nameSortedMap = new TreeMap<String,Integer>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

and

```
Map<Integer,String> idMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

Whenever I add or remove data, I do it on both maps.  If I am retrieving a username by ID, I'd call idMap.get(id) or idMap.contains(id) (to see if a user exists).  On the other hand, if I need to display a sorted list, I would use nameSortedMap.keySet(), which I gather should already be in name order, avoiding the need for additional work each time a sorted list is needed.

How's my thought process?  Is there a better or simpler way to accomplish this?  Thank you!

Comment: @BrendanLong dont you think that the process to insert/delete in a database costs more than in memory?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways I can think of:

- Use a database and index both columns. Databases are fast, and can be very small (see: [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)), but they're probably overkill if you don't need to save the data, or if this is the only thing you would use it for.
- Create a class containing both of your maps above, which handles all inserting and deleting. That way, you only have one place where you have to remember to do operations on both. This is one of the major selling points for [object oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29#As_information_hiding_mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont call the ordered list very often I dont think would be necessary to keep two maps, but if you prefer to do that. I would suggest you to create one class thtat extend the HashMap and implement the methods to handle both maps. Example:

```
public class UserMap extends HashMap<Integer, String> {

    TreeMap<String, Integer> nameSortedMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    @Override
    public String put(Integer key, String value) {
        String put = super.put(key, value);
        nameSortedMap.put(value, key);
        return put;
    }

    @Override
    public String remove(Object key) {
        String toRemove = get(key);
        if (toRemove != null) {
            remove(key);
            getOrderedName().remove(toRemove);
        }
        return toRemove;
    }

    public Set<String> getSortedNames() {
        return nameSortedMap.keySet();
    }

}
```